# Inserting a previously calculated value in a legend in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

This should be simple, but I haven't found it: I have a value (the coefficient R squared) previously calculated and I want to insert it in a legend in matplotlib. If the value calculated is `r_squared`, this is not working:

```
plt.plot(x, y, linestyle='solid', color='k', label=r'Fitting line with $R^{2} = $, r_squared')
```

It just don't read the value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use string formatting :

```
plt.plot(x, y, linestyle='solid', color='k', label="Fitting line with $R^{{2}} = {}".format(r_squared))
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `"Fitting line with $R^{{2}} = {}"` with double braces around 2 to preserve it from using in formatting?

Comment: Absolutely. Edited ;)

Comment: Thanks. By the way, do you know why you don't need to close the $?

Comment: What do you mean by not closing the $ ?